# Loading a class of unknown name in a dynamic location

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

Currently I am extracting files to the temp directory of the operating system. One of the files is a Python file containing a class which I need to get a handle of. The Python's file is known, but the name of the class inside the file is unknown. But it is safe to assume, that the there is only one single class, and that the class is a subclass of another.

I tried to work with `importlib`, but I am not able to get a handle of the class.

So far I tried:

```
# Assume 
# module_name contains the name of the class and     -> "MyClass"
# path_module contains the path to the python file   -> "../Module.py"
spec = spec_from_file_location(module_name, path_module)
module = module_from_spec(spec)
for pair in inspect.getmembers(module):
    print(f"{pair[1]} is class: {inspect.isclass(pair[1])}")
```

When I iterate over the members of the module, none of them get printed as a class.

My class in this case is called `BasicModel` and the Output on the console looks like this:

```
BasicModel is class: False
```

What is the correct approach to this?

Edit:

As the content of the file was requested, here you go:

```
class BasicModel(Sequential):

    def __init__(self, class_count: int, input_shape: tuple):
        Sequential.__init__(self)
        self.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
        self.add(Flatten())
        self.add(Dense(128, activation=nn.relu))
        self.add(Dense(128, activation=nn.relu))
        self.add(Dense(class_count, activation=nn.softmax))
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the file, so we can experiment with it?

Comment: I added the contents of the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dir()` to get the attributes of the file and `inspect` to check if the attribute is a class. If so, you can create an object.

Assuming that your file's path is `/tmp/mysterious` you can do this:

```
import importlib
import inspect
from pathlib import Path
import sys

path_pyfile = Path('/tmp/mysterious.py')
sys.path.append(str(path_pyfile.parent))
mysterious = importlib.import_module(path_pyfile.stem)

for name_local in dir(mysterious):
    if inspect.isclass(getattr(mysterious, name_local)):
        print(f'{name_local} is a class')
        MysteriousClass = getattr(mysterious, name_local)
        mysterious_object = MysteriousClass()
```

Comment: It does not really work, if I print out all items of the dir() call, i get those `__cached__ <class 'str'>
__doc__ <class 'str'>
__file__ <class 'str'>
__loader__ <class 'str'>
__name__ <class 'str'>
__package__ <class 'str'>
__spec__ <class 'str'>`

None of them is of type `class`

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies That's why I included the if-Statement. Only if that is True for name_local we can be sure it is a class. I added a line that prints the name of the class.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the function `import_module` does not take a path as parameter? The basis for my problem is, that I have a path to a python file and the name of the class and I need to import those. Also important is, that I only know those things during runtime.

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies Sorry, I overlooked this. My edited answer makes use of `pathlib` and `sys.path.append`. There might be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: To understand your edited solution correctly

`path_pyfile` is actually the directory, where the pyfile is in? And you add the parentfolder of that folder to sys?

Assuming pyfile's path is `/tmp/dir123/pyfile.py`, then you add `/tmp` to sys?

By the way I still have problems running this, it still crashes

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies No. `path_pyfile` is `/tmp/dir123/pyfile.py` `str(path_pyfile.parent)` would then be `/tmp/dir123/`. But the argument in the following line should have been `path_pyfile.stem`. I corrected that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230452/discussion-between-thomas-christopher-davies-and-durtal).